# Where to put MySQL connection to avoid code repetition in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the `mysql` module in Node.js. In my model file, currently, I'm specifying the connection constants in each method. However, this is taking up a lot of space and I know it's not ideal.

Here's what that looks like.

```
doSomething: () => {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : config.database.host,
        database : config.database.database,
        user     : config.database.user,
        password : config.database.password
    });

    connection.query( ... );
    connection.destroy();

},



doSomethingElse: () => {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : config.database.host,
        database : config.database.database,
        user     : config.database.user,
        password : config.database.password
    });

    connection.query( ... );
    connection.destroy();


},
```

Could anyone recommend a way to tidy things up a bit and reduce the redundant code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the connection once and pass it to module exports.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "db"
});

module.exports = conn;
```

Then you can import it in other files and use it.

```
var dbConnection = require('./dbConnection');

dbConnection.query();
```

However, instead of using `createConnection`, I recommend using `createPool` instead.

> Connections can be pooled to ease sharing a single connection, or
>   managing multiple connections.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const conn = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "db"
});

module.exports = conn;
```

You can use it like this. Make sure to `release` the connection after fetching data from the table:

```
var connectionPool = require('./dbConnection');

connectionPool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM table', (error, result) {
    connection.release();
    if(error) throw error;
  });
});
```

To close all connections in the pool:

```
connectionPool.end(function (err) {
  // all connections in the pool have ended
});
```

Comment: Thank you! And where would you terminate the connection?